# Convert SWF to MP4 and maintain Captions

Tags: video-conversion, swf

I have a large number of SWF files that must be converted into MP4 format.  In addition to that I need to retain the captions that are currently embedded/accessible via a button click within the SWF video.

I have tried this online conversion tool: https://cloudconvert.com/swf-to-mp4 which had worked in the past, but it is not working for this particular group of videos. The videos are made up of a bunch of images that are displayed throughout. When I perform the conversion they all are placed in the first second of the video.

I do have Adobe CC products, so if one of those can perform this function that would be great.

My desired result is either an MP4 with embedded Closed Captions or an MP4 and a vtt/srt/xml file that inlcudes the captions.

Comment: Please post an example.

Comment: Try to open those files with VLC. Then you can try: 1- to use vlc itself to convert/save in a different format them (best), 2- To use ffmpeg to convert them (good), 3- to use vlc to see them and record a video capturing what you see (bad). 4- to extract the photo and recreate the video (very bad). :-) ...

Answer (score 0):

Though not in the CC suite, but Adobe Captivate should do the job, methinks. It did for me a while back.
See: https://helpx.adobe.com/captivate/using/publish-projects-mp4-files.html

They offer a trial - http://www.adobe.com/products/captivate.html - though you'd need to check the T's&C's as there may be some limitation on the number of projects. The annual subscription is charged at 30 bucks a month.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of luck converting SWF files to MP4 using [Swivel](https://www.newgrounds.com/wiki/creator-resources/flash-resources/swivel). I've found it able to convert 'compressed' SWF files which no other converter could. It can also mix audio, so I'm sure it would be able to handle captions.